# UV unwrapping a circle onto a square without warping

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm modeling a satellite and I'm trying to texture a spherical part at the end of it. Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: reference]

The way I'm trying to achieve this is by UV unwrapping the circle onto a square texture and straightening the UVs.
[image: model]
[image: UVs]
However, no matter how I do it I get uneven warping on the texture which looks like this:
[image: bending]
I tried using quads only because in theory they should be stretched evenly but because they get triangulated when imported into Unity the warping is even more visible. Here is the same problem occurring when the quads are triangulated automatically.
[image: automatic triangulation]

Comment: The crossing edges where faces extending from the cylinder would be seem to have no purpose. Seems like it's unnecessary geometry.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys This was my attempt to triangulate the quads on my own since when it happens automatically the effect is more visible (the automatics triangulation isn't symmetrical). I've attached a screenshot of the same problem occurring with the triangulation happening automatically.

Comment: It doesn't have much to do with the problem, but there is an operator Triangulate Faces(Ctrl+T) in the Faces menu for that. It would just triangulate faces without making extra unnecessary geometry.  This particular situation improves only because you make more points for deformation to work more precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The texture gets warped, because it is straight in the image and it needs to go in circle on the geometry. It gets warped irregularly, because there is not enough geometry on the object. If you increased the density of the geometry it would warp better:

[image]

You could avoid the need to increase density of the mesh by simply making a texture that would not need to be warped by the UV map(leave the UV's unstraightened in a circle as they come after unwrapping and then make a texture matching them).

Comment: Yeah this seems to be the way to go. Sucks that I have to add all this extra geometry, but due to how my shader work is Unity I'm restricted to a limited amount of textures and can't prepare special circular textures for this case.